# SliverGrid grid cells are rectangular and not squares and am not sure why

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a Gridview within a SliverGrid, and am setting width and height to 200 via maxCrossAxisExtent, mainAxisExtent. However, the grids are more rectangles than squares and do not know what I am missing.

```
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("ListView"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                [
                  Container(
                    height: 100.0,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text('welcome to Inference.link'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            // here is the grid view
            SliverGrid(
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                maxCrossAxisExtent: 200.0,
                mainAxisExtent: 200.0,
                mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                childAspectRatio: 1,
              ),
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(_buildTiles()),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  
  // making the grid tiles
  List<Widget> _buildTiles() {
    final List<Widget> tiles = <Widget>[];
    for (int i = 0; i < models.length; i++) {
      tiles.add(new GridTile(
          child: new InkResponse(
        enableFeedback: true,
        child: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: colors[(new Random()).nextInt(3)]),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              models[i],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () => didSelectModel != null ? didSelectModel!(models[i]) : null,
      )));
    }

    return tiles;
  }
```

below are the rectangular grids. any suggestion is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because the number of columns is not defined which is supposed to be interpreted as a number of columns in a table which I believe it causes the problem.

so we need to specify width according to screen.

try this it work for me well.

```
final mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);

 return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("ListView"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                [
                  Container(
                    height: 100.0,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text('welcome to Inference.link'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            // here is the grid view
            SliverGrid(
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                maxCrossAxisExtent: mediaQuery.size.width / 3,,
                mainAxisExtent: mediaQuery.size.width / 3,
                mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                childAspectRatio: 1,
              ),
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(_buildTiles()),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  
  // making the grid tiles
  List<Widget> _buildTiles() {
    final List<Widget> tiles = <Widget>[];
    for (int i = 0; i < models.length; i++) {
      tiles.add(new GridTile(
          child: new InkResponse(
        enableFeedback: true,
        child: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: colors[(new Random()).nextInt(3)]),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              models[i],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () => didSelectModel != null ? didSelectModel!(models[i]) : null,
      )));
    }

    return tiles;
  }
```